# Spring MVC Multi-part File - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, file, tomcat, tomcat7, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to upload some file with Spring 3 MVC, but I always get the same exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)Ljava/util/List;
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:155)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:904)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:747)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I found in dependencies this method: `ServletFileUpload.parseRequest`, so it exists. I read that there might be some other library for example in Tomcat's lib folder but i couldn't find anything.

This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FilesController {


@Autowired
EventFileUploadValidator eventValidator;

@Autowired
Configuration config;

@InitBinder("fileupload")
public void initEventFileBinde(WebDataBinder bind){
    bind.setValidator(eventValidator);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addEventFile", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadEventFile(@ModelAttribute("fileupload") FileUploadModel file, BindingResult results, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,  Model model, HttpSession session) throws IOException, NoConfigurationFoundException{

    if(!results.hasErrors()){
        MultipartFile uplodadFile = file.getFile();
        if(uplodadFile != null){

           // String path = config.getProperty("upload_file_directory").toString();
           // String filename = uplodadFile.getName();
           // uplodadFile.transferTo(new File(path+"/"+filename));

        }
    }

    return ViewHelper.EventsListView;
}


}
```

dependiences in POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>             
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>             
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>         
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>                
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>                
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>          
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>  
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>  
        <version>1.4</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I dont know what to do... I am using Tomcat 7.0.42 on Windows

Comment: Do you think you could run the `mvn dependency:tree` command and post the results. This will make it easier to figure out if there are conflicting versions of commons-fileupload

Comment: Look like some incompatible version of commons fileupload

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError is a classic case of version mismatch. Check the dependency tree in maven to get a clear picture perhaps

Comment: I checked it. There are no conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I have found where is the problem. When maven is building target path for deploying, it doesn't remove old libs, but it only adds newest, so when I had resolved all conflicts (I changed version), Maven add new jar file with new lib's version. I removed not required files and everything work fine.

Those files was in WEB-INF\target\lib directory.